# Facing login issue with loginWithAccesstoken for docusign

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, docusignapi

Update: problem Resolved: Check below comments

Using Docusign as a framework, during login it is giving below error.

```
Error Domain=user.additional.data.fetch.error Code=-1016 "Unable to fetch additional data for user - Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to fetch additional data for user - Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, NSLocalizedFailureReason=USER_ADDITIONAL_DATA_FETC
```

Below is data used for login

```
NSString * userName = @"D*****y";
        NSString * accessToken = @"eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAAAABAAUABwAAEozC_7LZSAgAAFKv0EKz2UgCADH-vovuycJOtx8b-0T42BgVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAMDFmZmFjMmQtMWU2Zi00OTk2LTlmMTgtM2E0MWMzNmVkZmMwIgAkAAAAMDFmZmFjMmQtMWU2Zi00OTk2LTlmMTgtM2E0MWMzNmVkZmMwMACAkGNv-rLZSDcAct05PIuJOEitb0Mnkb4e_A.UdjyVjBFNUL6Lq7H5ulDAOe_NhpygYGQHKUyAJYdEthfo8EXIX6DEE5aLZLdKxnB-CjrTFz9NWjGkIVUFpXuDPukWgWkuWDRNI0s57fe09rws4JAsIovlh0regrd1eh-wGUwAhLLqzivtmz-fR23PVryCeUll-JsS-y_PCfrfZDQJj4JQ3D44olnSDvvYQ-tyDBChwLatPiwWBnD9ef4UHWZzp2dYbnURhkhVM7SgXXnhkz5FF1J-bUmSVPURDAkGIx8TA5VpXPA2gxt5ydo01IDk5pe1OWJCBC9Tue89SSLysum1NoFbzvhpGPRB2IMDmKg7J8QYoSy1-*******";
NSString * userId = @"8bbefe31-****-4ec2-****-1bfb44f8d818";
NSString * accountId = @"1******6";
NSString * email = @"kdines*****@gmail.com";
NSString * demoHostApi = @"https://account-d.docusign.com/";
NSString * integratorKey = @"01ffac2d-****-4996-****-3a41c36edfc0";
```

Below function is used for login

```
  [DSMManager loginWithAccessToken:accessToken accountId:accountId userId:userId userName:userName email:email host:[NSURL URLWithString:hostApiUrl] integratorKey:integratorKey completion:^(DSMAccountInfo *accountInfo, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is - Your content type is `text/html` - It probably wants `application/json`

Comment: @Paulw11 It is class method of Docusign DSMManager class which is already created, I am just using it. There is something else which i missed

Comment: The other possibility is that the Docusign endpoint is returning some HTML instead of the expected JSON response.  If you can capture the response that is being returned there may be some hint, but really their endpoint or their SDK has a bug if it is returning something that the SDK can't parse.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct endpoint url?  Shouldn't it be `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi` or `https://www.docusign.net` ? - See https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k7ZZ/production-endpointurl-for-requests

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for valuable answers, after changing endpoint is working fine, Actully using endpoint of demo application provided by Docusign itself, so I was confused about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, off, it appears you have a hardcoded access token. That may work for a while, but these tokens expire after 8 hours and it's not a long term solution to copy/paste them into your code.

As Paul pointed out the URL to make API calls in DocuSign (for the eSignature API) are : https://demo.docusign.net/restapi in the developer account and https://www.docusign.net/restapi in production (although you may have a different one for your account)

Best practice is to call the [getUserInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) which provides the list of one or more accounts for the logged in user. The account information includes the baseURI which can be used to make API calls.

Comment: Thanks for valuable input. Actually at development period using accessToken hardcoded, we will make it to dynamic.